# Find Closest element with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm searching to have the closest element address-department:

```html
<div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="address-zipcode">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="address-department">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="city">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="country">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="address-zipcode">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="address-department">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="city">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="country">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm doing ajax, when i tape on zip-code then I autocomplete address-department, but now I have 2 blocks address and I want when I "input" on address-zipcode then he changes only the closest address-department.

I tried with `this.closest('.field').closest('.field.address-department')` but it's not working.
Do you know how I can do that ? Thank !

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?  Because putting these groups of elements into their own containing `<div>` elements would make the logic *much* more straightforward.

Comment: Please share the JS which you've tried to create a Minimal, Reproducible [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838675/find-closest-element-with-same-class#69838675)

Comment: @David Actually yes I have a div who take a block address

Comment: @pham01: If you can modify the HTML to wrap each of these repeated sections in their own parent element then you can use a combination of `.closest()` (to get to the parent) and `.find()` (to get back down to the intended child) to find the element you want.

Comment: @David Thank you, i did this.closest('.field').parentElement.querySelector('.address-department')

Comment: When you type like that `'.field.address-department'` it means select the element that have class `field` **and** class `address-department`. in your case this is wrong, because the element `address-department` is a child inside `field`, so if you want to select a parent and child. add a space between classes names.

Comment: What about nextSibling () ?

Comment: this.parent().nextElementSibling.children('.field.address-department') ???

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the naming `closest` is a bit confusing. you can think of `closest` as a reverse querySelector.
It will basicly find the next parent element that matches the statement.
so you kind of can go down but not up again with that.

I would suggest just using `querySelector` for this.
This would be independent of structure, order and depth.

Basicly: move back to a common base (in this case a surrounding form) and search the element.

You can find this common base by calling `closest('your-base')` or by accessing if via ID, or whatever.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('base');
  
  const department = form.querySelector('.address-department');
  if(!department) return;
  
  department.classList.toggle('found');
})

button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('search-start');
  
  const department = form.closest('form').querySelector('.address-department');
  if(!department) return;
  
  department.classList.toggle('found');
})
```

```css
.found {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="base">
  <div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="address-zipcode" id="search-start">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="address-department">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="city">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="country">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="address-zipcode">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="address-department">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="city">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" class="country">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<button id="button">Find Department from Base</button>
<button id="button2">Find Department from Input</button>
```